# 2x2 ANOVA interactions

Tags: anova, spss, interaction

I'm doing a masters project where I look for effects of font (fluent, disfluent) on two populations' (control, dyslexic) reading comprehension. SPSS only gives me a significant main effect for population, not font, and no significant interaction between population and font. However, when eyeballing the graph, I can see a clear interaction (lines actually cross): as the controls' comprehension gets better on disfluent font texts, the dyslexics' comprehension gets worse (lines goes in the opposite direction) on the disfluent font material. Why is SPSS not reporting significant results for the interaction here? How do I go about reporting my findings?

Comment: Does it make sense to think that non-dyslexic people have an easier time reading the more obscure the font is?

Comment: There's been this research that obscure font activates deeper levels of processing during reading. It's a bit counterintuitive, I agree, but interesting to look into.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the effect is not large enough to be significant, given the sample size and the variation within the groups.

If you included these two variables for strong theoretical reasons, my view is that you should report them. Non-significant results can be both important and interesting.

If your N is large and you have other independent variables that may help explain comprehension (e.g. age, education etc) then including those variables may help.

If you can show us the n, means and sds, min and max for each of the four groups that may help us understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'm going to carry on recruiting participants (10 for each of the four levels) and then check if the effect is large enough to have statistical significance in the interactions. Many thanks again.

Comment: though if I don't get significant results, I'll still report them, just like you said about the strong theoretical reasons.